# Ideas for designing relational schema?

Tags: database, schema

I am a bit confused as to what my professor told me. I know you make a schema off of **x(entities) + y(multivalue attributes) + z(many-many relationships)**.
My question is, *do I include the associative entities in as well?* I cannot submit a picture because my reputation is not high enough, which frustrates me because you need to see my diagram in order to make sense of my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use Gliffy, an online database design program. I figured out how to represent my illustrations here.